# 404 for an existing valid REST API resource

Tags: rest, metamug

I saved the below xml resource file as state.xml and was trying to access it from `localhost:7000/covid/v1.0/state`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Resource xmlns="http://xml.metamug.net/resource/1.0" v="1.0">
    <Request method="GET" item="true">
        <Desc>Get state information</Desc>
        <Sql id="stateInfo">
            select * from india_state_info 
            where id = $id
        </Sql>
    </Request>
</Resource>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning **404** because the *resource* expects a path param `id` in the URL since you've marked `item=true` while creating the resource.
So the call:
`localhost:7000/covid/v1.0/state`
It is not able to find any `state` resource which takes `collection` request since only item request with path param are accepted.
So 404 is a valid response in this case. Checkout Metamug [docs](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file#item-request) for more info.

Comment: I see. my first guess was that `state` resource doesn't exist. But it did exist and there was no typo in the name as well